# Formula for auto filling cells

Tags: excel, formula

I have following formula for auto filling 300 cells.

`=AND(ROW()>=3,(12*(ROW()-3)+COLUMN())<=$E$2)`

It could take the command for fixing starting row but the problem is here I'm not able to fix columns. I want to fix the number of columns so that when I enter the formula only cells defined under the area of starting row and ending column shall be filled.

Right now I have to select the area myself upto the desired number of columns and then enter the formula for auto filling cells.

How can I modify the formula to fix the column? So that if I want cells to be filled upto 12 then it shall be done automatically. Need help!!

Comment: Hey why the downvoting ?

Comment: in which column you are writing above code? how is your data in excel?  maybe example would be better. Use [google doc](https://docs.google.com)

Comment: @dotNetSoldier The close votes (as opposed to downvotes) are because this question is off topic. It is not programming related

Answer (score 1):

1. In Excel Record a Macro
2. Do all the operations - fill in formula and fix the columns (you can fine-tune it later)
3. After finishing recording the macro in Excel > press Alt + F11 and you can see VBA code.

You wont be able to change columns with a Formula. You should be able to work out the corresponding VBA ode per the manual operations you do whilst recording macro's.

So if there is something your having problems coding up in VBA > record a macro and see what code excel produces to complete the manual operation programatially.